# Hide edit control when checkbox is checked in windows installer dialog

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I have a dialog box with a checkbox and two edit fields beneath it. I want the edit fields to be grayed out or disabled as soon as the checkbox is checked. I [know this is possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) by adding an entry to the ControlCondition table in the MSI, but I don't know what to use for the Condition and I can't find any examples with checkboxes for windows installer.

I know I'm close. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am trying to do this in an installer project, so I don't have access to the Dialog code directly. Instead I'm trying to edit the Dialog in an MSI editor like Orca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I was closer than I thought!

Using Orca, I had a checkbox called Checkbox1 with Property set to USEWINAUTH.

Now, in the ControlCondition table, I added 4 entries:

```
Dialog_: CustomTextA
Control_: Edit2
Action: Disable
Condition: USEWINAUTH=1

Dialog_: CustomTextA
Control_: Edit2
Action: Enable
Condition: USEWINAUTH<>1
```

And then repeat for the other Edit control.

I'll end up doing this with a script so I don't have to edit the MSI by hand with Orca every time I build the project.

Answer (score 0):

can you just set their `Visible` attribute to false? Or hell, just set the `Enabled` attribute to false.

Comment: I could do it manually, but how would checking a checkbox trigger that? That's the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: You will need an event handler

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm using orca to edit the msi. Is there a way to do it that way? I'm not too familiar with this so correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you can add events in ControlEvents table and do something with that.

Comment: thats what it looks like according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?